# Problem with double horizontal margins appearing in IE6 and IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I'm having a wee issue with a double margin appearing between `<div>`'s. It works fine in FF, Opera, Safari etc. but not in IE6 and IE7 (surprisingly enough).

There's meant to be a left floated `<div>` beside a right floated `<div>` and then underneath there is another lefty and righty. There's only meant to be 24px between them but in IE6 & 7 there's 47px.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="contentwrapper">
        <div class="infobox leftinfo row1">
            <div class="searchForm">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="infobox rightinfo row1">
            <div class="searchForm">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="infobox leftinfo row2">
            <div class="textstuff">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="infobox rightinfo row2">
            <div class="textstuff">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#contentwrapper{
    padding:23px;
}
#content{
    background-image:url(../img/contentbg.jpg);
    border: 1px solid #81b8de;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px 5px #80cafe;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px 5px #80cafe;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 5px #80cafe;
    behavior: url(/sponster/PIE.htc);
    position:relative;
}
.infobox{
    border: 1px solid #4eed4e;
    background:url(../img/infoboxbg.png) repeat-x;
    height:100%;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 12px -1px #406020;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 12px -1px #406020;
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px -1px #406020;
    behavior: url(/sponster/PIE.htc);
    position:relative;
}
.leftinfo{
    float:left;
    width:442px;
    margin-bottom:24px;
}
.rightinfo{
    float:right;
    width:442px;
    margin-bottom:24px;
}
```

N.B. The `row1` class is just so a JavaScript file can make sure the heights of each side-by-side `<div>` are the same.  It's a jQuery plugin: http://www.cssnewbie.com/equalheights-jquery-plugin and there doesn't appear to be any issues with it.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to HMTL in between rows:

```
<br class="cl">
```

It will look like this:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="contentwrapper">
    <div class="infobox leftinfo row1">
      <div class="searchForm">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="infobox rightinfo row1">
      <div class="searchForm">
      </div>
    </div>
    <br class="cl">
    <div class="infobox leftinfo row2">
      <div class="textstuff">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="infobox rightinfo row2">
      <div class="textstuff">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Add this to CSS:

```
.cl{clear:both}
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>"Double 'vertical' margins" is a well known issue in IE 6, but it's not supposed to be an issue in IE7.</s>  **EDIT:**  My first answer was incorrect due to misunderstanding over the original title of this thread, which read:   "Problem with double **vertical** margins appearing in IE6 and IE7"

After you apply the fix below, double check your DOCTYPE and run your code through the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) just to make sure everything else is good.

**Using an empty `<div>` is a very common method to "clear" your floats despite the accepted answer in this thread which recommends using a line-break element `<br>`.**

An empty `<div>` has no height [as demonstrated in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zMZzG/3/) by the red `<div>`'s with class `.empty`.  Notice the empty red `<div>`'s are invisible and take up no space whatsoever between the blue `<div>`'s.

Other elements such as `<br />` have a line-height which may introduce other spacing issues [as demonstrated in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zMZzG/4/).   Note how you can see a full empty line between each blue `<div>`.

Therefore, add `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` between your `<div>` rows:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="contentwrapper">
    <div class="infobox leftinfo row1">
      <div class="searchForm">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="infobox rightinfo row1">
      <div class="searchForm">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

    <div class="infobox leftinfo row2">
      <div class="textstuff">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="infobox rightinfo row2">
      <div class="textstuff">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the input. I had tried that but it's didn't work. From what I had read that was an issue affecting only horizontal margins anyway. Thanks for the input anyway.

Comment: @julia:  Sorry, I misread your question and thought it was a horizontal margin issue.  I've re-worked my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Paweł:  **No, not exactly**.  Applying the `clear: both;` within a `<br>` element is uncommon and risky to layout because it has line-height.  **I recommend that `clear: both;` be applied within an empty `<div>` which is a much more common practice.**

Comment: @Paweł:  The `.empty` red `<div>`'s [in this Fiddle are totally invisible and take up no space whatsoever](http://jsfiddle.net/zMZzG/3/), exactly as per the W3C spec.